# Using MediatR in a console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, mediatr

Does anyone know how to implement MediatR in a console application, to call a handler function using the _mediatr.Send(obj) syntax. I'm using the .Net 6 framework.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14):

First, you must install these packages:

1. [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/)
2. [MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR)
3. [MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)

Then you can get `IMediator` from `DI` and use it.

```
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Reflection;

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var mediator = serviceCollection.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

//mediator.Send(new Command());
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be working in a console application in .NET 8 and MediatR 12.

```
HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddTransient<IProcessingService, ProcessingService>(); // my own service where MediatR is injected
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => {
    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
});

using IHost host = builder.Build();

var processingService = host.Services.GetService<IProcessingService>();

processingService.Process();
```